# Save Environment "Data" and "Values" along with script in R

Tags: r, save, environment

Title says it mostly. I want to be able to save all my data frames, vectors, variables, etc along with the code into a single file so that I dont have to reimport data and recreate the dfs, vectors, etc each time I open R. I have tried looking through the Global Options but havent found anything that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using R studio, when you want to close the application, it asks you if you want to save **image** file. Select the image and save it. This will allow you to save the data frames and other values as well.

[image]

you can also clean data frames before saving the image, so you only keep values and data frames that are important for you. **Attention:** saving large data frames image will cause a delay in loading R every time you are going to open it.

Comment: Ok thanks I wasn't sure what it meant by image so I never did lol. Will that also save libraries used in that specific file or will I have to rerun those each time?

Comment: @JesseJohnson As far as I know, the library should be loaded every time. You can simply write code in the top of your script and load required libraries everytime when you run the script